# Does BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable() remove items

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Can someone confirm that the below code definitely removes items from the BlockingCollection

```
foreach (var item in myCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

It does say on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) that it does but I just need to be re-assured as I have a near real time application accepting inputs into 4 of these collections 60ms apart and after a while my app is freezing and I dont know why and just wanted to be sure that items are being removed.

Comment: I think you need to post more code. Also, have you tested this?  If so, what is the behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) says:

> **Return value:**
>   An IEnumerable that *removes* and returns items from the collection.

(emphasis added)